# Build with docker and --privileged

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, amazon-lex

I'm using [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ai/build-a-voice-kit-with-amazon-lex-and-a-raspberry-pi/) to Build a Voice Kit with Amazon Lex and a Raspberry Pi, but I need to use Docker. 
The problem is that the script that the guide curls and runs requires access to /dev/tty. I can grant access to /dev/tty when *running* docker containers, but I don't know how to do that when building containers.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM resin/rpi-raspbian

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

#The script requires these
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install iputils-ping

#The script has to be run with sudo priviliges but not as root
USER root
ADD /sudoers.txt /etc/sudoers
RUN chmod 440 /etc/sudoers


RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash lex
RUN echo 'lex:test' | chpasswd

RUN curl https://get.pimoroni.com/phatdac | bash 

USER lex

EXPOSE 80

#Comment the last RUN command and uncomment this
#CMD curl https://get.pimoroni.com/phatdac | bash
```

And when I try to build the container with

```
docker build -t raspi1 .
```

it crashes on the script, because it can't access /dev/tty.

When running a container, I can use this script to grant access to /dev/tty and /dev/snd

```
#!/bin/sh

 docker run -ti --rm \
     -v /dev/snd:/dev/snd \
      --privileged \
     raspi7
```

and then try to use the script on the startup with CMD in the Dockerfile. But if I do that, then I need to use the script every time when running and I also need to do RUN on other stuff after the script has finished which would be nice to have on the Dockerfile when building.

TLDR;
How to grant privileges to /dev/tty and /dev/snd when building a docker image?

Comment: unrelated, but you should group your RUN (see https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/) , and your line `user ROOT` is useless, as by default your are root, unless you do `USER xxx`what you do later

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40442284/exposing-a-tty-device-in-a-docker-container-with-docker-for-mac/40442502

Comment: Thanks, but those don't solve this problem yet.

Answer (score 8):

Docker currently doesn't support exposing devices, or for that matter privileged operations when building.

According to @cpuguy83 what you are doing now - building a portable image without access to the host and completing the configuration when the container is first started - is the right thing to do:

> > Doing this kind of stuff at first container start is exactly the right way to go.
> >     It's a runtime configuration it shouldn't be in the image.

See [bountysource](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/964893-docker-build-should-support-privileged-operations).

There is also and old but still open [moby](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1916)'s issue.

Answer (score 8):

The [moby](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1916)'s issue mentioned by @Greg has been closed.

It is now possible to build images with privileged rights with `docker buildx`:

1. In *Dockerfile* ([ref](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/syntax.md)),

   1. set the Dockerfile version in the beginning of file:

      ```
      # syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.3-labs
      ```
   2. add the `--security=insecure` option to the `RUN` commands that require privileged operations:

      ```
      RUN somecommand
      ```

      becomes

      ```
      RUN --security=insecure somecommand
      ```
2. create and use a *docker-container driver* to build the image ([ref](https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole/issues/975#issuecomment-1008865353)):

   ```sh
   docker buildx create --driver-opt image=moby/buildkit:master  \
                        --use --name insecure-builder \
                        --buildkitd-flags '--allow-insecure-entitlement security.insecure'
   docker buildx use insecure-builder
   docker buildx build --allow security.insecure ...(other build args)...
   docker buildx rm insecure-builder
   ```

However, note that this method has some restrictions so far. A *docker-container driver* has no access to `docker image` ([ref](https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/301#issuecomment-639746416)), so all the images referenced by `FROM` need to be in a image registry. And for the built image to be visible to `docker image`, you may need to add the `output` option in the `docker buildx build` command.

Comment: Thank you for that tidbit ... I'm trying to build linux-from-scratch in a docker container, and I needed a chroot complete with /dev, /proc, /sys, and /dev/pts .... to complete the build process.  And it forced me to do in a docker run what should be done in a docker build, if for no other reason I so I don't have to rebuild 30 packages because teh 31st one failed to compile.  I've been seriously conisdering learning go and hacking buildx, just to be able to say for i in proc sys dev dev/pts; do mkdir -p /$i ; mount --bind /$i /lfs/$i; done.

I'm so happy I could plottz.

Comment: adding container  in the list of containers, you need the `--load` option -`docker buildx build --load --allow security.insecure -t my_container`
https://docs.docker.com/build/drivers/docker-container/#loading-to-local-image-store

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably that /dev/snd doesn't exist inside your docker image.  When you run your container, you are actually mounting your host OS /dev/snd inside the container so that your script can be run.  Take a look at the following:

```
[INSERT] > cat Dockerfile
FROM resin/rpi-raspbian

RUN ls /dev && ls /dev/tty && ls /dev/snd


[INSERT] > docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  39.94kB
Step 1/2 : FROM resin/rpi-raspbian
 ---> d008ca006edc
Step 2/2 : RUN ls /dev && ls /dev/tty && ls /dev/snd
 ---> Running in 0b738007c71c
core
fd
full
mqueue
null
ptmx
pts
random
shm
stderr
stdin
stdout
tty
urandom
zero
/dev/tty
/bin/ls: cannot access /dev/snd: No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c ls /dev && ls /dev/tty && ls /dev/snd' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

As you can see, /dev/tty exists, and you have access to it.  /dev/snd does not exist, and you aren't inside a running container so you can't mount it as a volume (which you are doing when running the container). I would recommend trying to more fully understand what the script you are running is doing, assess whether it needs access to the host machine's /dev/snd, and if so you may only run the script inside the running container as an image doesn't have any concept of a host machine.