# Is it possible to mount a directory in a docker image during build?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

Starting with the Docker tutorial, I modify the Dockerfile to contain just

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/base:0-jammy
RUN mkdir proc && mount --bind /proc ./foo
```

From the directory hosting the Dockerfile I issue command

```
docker build -t getting-started .
```

I expect this docker image to mount `/proc` at `./foo` during the build, but I actually get:

```
 > [2/2] RUN mkdir foo && mount --bind /proc ./foo:
#5 0.399 mount: /foo: permission denied.
```

Is there a way to grant permissions to the build process so it can mount proc inside the Docker image?

Comment: Possibly this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72342814/2303356

Comment: Could use `RUN --mount`, but make sure docker version is above 18.09 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050899/how-to-mount-host-volumes-into-docker-containers-in-dockerfile-during-build

Comment: you cannot do `&& mount --bind`

Comment: Why do you want to?  You can `COPY` files from the host (technically the build context) into the image, but an image build never creates anything besides its immediate image inside Docker space.

Comment: My question is better posed as trying to mount `/proc`. That brings up https://kinvolk.io/blog/2018/04/towards-unprivileged-container-builds/. I'm trying to run a chroot inside the docker container and to do that I need to mount proc inside the chroot.

Comment: Well, @DavidMaze, one reason would be building a linux-from-scratch instance in a chroot, with /proc, /dev, and /sys mounted.  If you can't do that, you have to first have a shell script outside of docker to run the process and switch between build and run and commit or however people do that ... and handle errors, and then you have to cut the work up into tiny blocks because if package #50 fails to compile, the other 49 successful builds are not cached, and you gotta start all over.

Answer (score 0):

On windows:

```
docker buildx create --driver-opt image=moby/buildkit:master ^
    --use --name insecure-builder ^
    --buildkitd-flags "--allow-insecure-entitlement security.insecure"
docker buildx use insecure-builder
docker buildx build --allow security.insecure .
docker buildx rm insecure-builder
```